# PHP's database operation not working property in IIS?

Tags: php, mysql, iis

After this statement:

```
insert into table... value(..,"It\'s my title")
```

In database I can see :

```
It\'s my title
```

It only happens when in IIS.How to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled on IIS. Turn it off. See [Disabling Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

Comment: Was it on? Did you change it? Did you restart IIS after changing it?

Comment: I only restarted my specific site inside IIS.That's why it didn't work.Is it a bug of IIS?

Answer (score 0):

I think for that statement, because you are using double quotes you don't need to escape the single quote

You can try this instead:

```
insert into table... value(..,'It\'s my title')
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the magic_quotes_gpc setting in your php.ini

Answer (score 0):

First of all disable [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php), it is deprecated anyway. You can use either of [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) functions.

```
    // disable magic_quotes_runtime
    if (get_magic_quotes_runtime())
    {
        @set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
    }
```